# grid-gap , column-gap not working when no sibling is present

Tags: html, css, css-grid

css grid gap seems to work only when there is sibling at it's right side or down side.

see below example

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px 20px;
  border:2px solid yellow
}



.wrapper > div {
  border:2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div>One</div>
   <div>Two</div>
   <div>Three</div>
   <div>Four</div>
   <div>Five</div>
</div>
```

[image: see image below.]

how to make space at the right side, without any margins or  or padding but using only grid-gap.

Comment: @Paulie_D i just want gap at the end also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how `gap` is supposed to work. Its for space *between* grid rows / columns etc.

Since margin/padding are apparently not an option here I can think of two possible soutions but there may be more.

### Option 1

Adjust the width of the divs using `calc`.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
  border: 2px solid yellow
}

.wrapper>div {
  border: 2px solid green;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
  <div>Five</div>
</div>
```

### Option 2

Add a second column that isn't used..

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 20px;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
  border: 2px solid yellow
}

.wrapper>div {
  border: 2px solid green;
  grid-column: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
  <div>Five</div>
</div>
```